# request docusign signature through app for composite template

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am creating docusign envelope with API call [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7Baccountid%7D/envelopes)

where I am using composite template and specifying tabs information

REQUEST

```
{    
    "emailSubject": "Template",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "a975e665-8888888888888-3268f3fb0d19"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                                "name": "Test user",
                                "recipientId": "76987934",
                                "clientUserId":"11111111",
                                "roleName": "Tester",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                             "tabLabel": "Newtest",
                                             "value": "ssssssssssssss"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Envelope does gets created.

Then I am creating recipient using API call
[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/envelopes/%7BenvelopeId%7D/recipients)

REQUEST :

```
{
   "signers":[
   {
       "name":"Test user",
       "email":"test@gmail.com",
       "recipientId":"76987934",
       "clientUserId":"11111111",
       "recipientType":"signer"
   }
 ]
}
```

Above API call creates an recipient

Then I am calling createRecipientView API call [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/envelopes/%7BenvelopeId%7D/views/recipient)

REQUEST :

```
{
   "email": "test@gmail.com",
   "authenticationMethod": "email",
   "clientUserId": "11111111",
   "returnUrl": "https://www.example.com",
   "userName": "Test user"
}
```

This does opens a view for user with given templateid but the tab fields are not shown as pre-filled.

Can someone please help me to show template fields as pre-filled.

I did tried below request for createReceipent API call

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "name": "Test user",
      "recipientId": "76987934",
      "tabs": {           
        "textTabs": [ 
          {
            "tabLabel": "Newtest",
            "value": "ssssssssssssss"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But this one is not working, as mentioned in documentation

Answer (score 0):

Good job on creating the envelope. Don't create **another** recipient. Instead, when you create the envelope, include a `clientUserId` attribute and value as part of the Signer Recipient object.

You'll the be able to create the recipient view (the signing ceremony view).

This [live example](https://codepen.io/docusign/full/MWXPKJY) adds the `clientUserId` to a recipient that is first defined in a template.

Comment: I have added clientUserId while createEnvelope API call. If I skip the step to createRecipient then it gives me error of "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT".